# Extracting pages of Xelatex created PDF in Acrobat requires password

Tags: pdf, printing, xepersian

I have a .tex file and after compiling with XeLatex , when I want to extract pages of the PDF or open a single-page PDF in Illustrator, it tells the file is Password-Protected
(in Adobe Acrobat, no extraction is allowed :tools>content editing>pages>extract)
Does any body have idea about this?
As an example, consider the pdf created of the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,B5paper]{book}
    \usepackage{xepersian}
    \settextfont{Yas} %or {Scheherazade}
    \setlatintextfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
f=(f_1^{- 2}+f_2^{- 2})^{- \frac{1}{2} }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

the pdf and log file creaded of the code can be downloaded here:
https://ufile.io/9rc3w
and a screenshot of the Properties>Security Tab is appended.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a minimal document. Does this depend on the font? I don't have the Yas font, but changing it to Scheherazade I can't reproduce the problem with Adobe Acrobat Pro (no Illustrator to test with.)

Comment: Glad to hear that and appreciate your help, the problem is independent of the font and still resist although I've changed it to Scheherazade. Something is wrong with the xepersian package

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and edit your question to show the output? Also is there anything in the log file that might indicate some security measures being made?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the file properties, tab security from adobe?

Comment: @AlanMunn: I didn't understand how to show the output; instead I uploaded the PDF file, also the Yas font can be downloaded here(after waiting 5 seconds): https://www.fontyab.com/download/?id=7044

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the image is appended, however, when the xepersian package is not invoked, the issue is gone and extraction or editing in AI is possible

Comment: We need to see the log file. Is you system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: the log file can be downloaded via the modified link in question, Im using  Texlive18 with recently updated packages

Comment: Hm. Well bidi.sty contains code to change the security settings. But I'm quite at loss to understand why they are used on your system and why you get the specific security settings (the default value is another). What happens if you load only bidi? What happens if you add `\pdfencryptsetup{permissionflags=4095}` to your preamble. Are the settings then changed?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Finally, by updating packages with `tlmgr` and re-compiling the code, the issue is solved and the extraction button is activated, 
I want to thank you for your help.

Comment: Your bidi version was a bit older than mine. It could be that there was an error in it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes maybe,such errors needs a high knowledge about the structures. if this way it wouldnt be solved, it seems you could somehow fix it.